# Is there any way to gain access to an HttpContext object in a Quartz.NET job?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Is there any way to gain access to the HttpContext object from a Quartz.NET job?  HttpContext.Current and the likes do not seem to work with Quartz.NET jobs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a way.
Just set **HttpContext.Current** to **JobDataMap** when instantiating new scheduler(probably in Application_Start event in Global.asax) like this:

```
jobDetail.JobDataMap["context"] = HttpContext.Current;
```

Then access it in Execute method like this:

```
HttpContext context = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["context"] as HttpContext;
```

Comment: This is a very dangerous suggestion. You are making a reference to the context which will become null once the associated request is complete

Comment: @xximjasonxx Dangerous!. When you access the object in Execute method, you are in another thread which Quartz will handle it(in other word, you are in Quartz's wold) and also the associated request is long gone. Seriously nothing dangerous gonna happen ;)

Comment: Dangerous is a relative term. What I meant was, simply, that you will likely begin to get unexplained errors based on timing as the context becomes null at the conclusion of the request. Never a good idea to depend on something that may not be there

Comment: You should see HttpContext.Current as an object that once copied to someplace and not related to anything anymore and only you can use it's values which was available when were in asp.net pipeline.

Comment: Doubtful. HttpContext.Current is passed by reference, not by value. Most of what I have read on Quartz does suggest not using the Context for this purpose, as Marko points out. If you can point out specific documentation that negates this, I will gladly withdraw my claim

Comment: This solution helps me to pass HttpContext and be safe in Global.aspx, but not guaranteed in general pages. My target is HttpContext.Current.Application level, so I think it's safe enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

Jobs are ran on different threads that do not know about a HTTP request that has happened at some point. The job might run after the request was processed and thus the context would be invalid anyway.

With frameworks like ASP.NET MVC you can do some things without actual context, like generating route urls etc but request and response (pretty much the context) are not available.

You need to partition the responsibilities so that Quartz jobs can work autonomously.